# Tinkerpop/gremlin merge vertices (and edges)

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Is there an easy way to replace or merge vertices and keep/merge existing edges? Or just manually copy all properties from the vertex and recreate existing edges and all (meta-)properties and then drop the superfluous vertex?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your use-case? Are you talking about an import? And if so, how do you import the vertices? Which graph db are you using?

Comment: My use case is a knowledge graph which contains data from different sources. This data can describe different aspects of the same entities. The different sources do not always have common identifiers for these entities. When having enough data I can identify which vertices are about the same entity and so I want to merge those vertices (including their vertices). The db I am using should not matter but I am using JanusGraph (with Cassandra and Elasticsearch).

Comment: The db does matter, I wouldn't have asked otherwise. Each db has its own extra features. So, for Janus it might be a good idea to write a custom vertex program. How do you match the vertices? Do you use a long running OLAP job or something short lived in OLTP?

Comment: @DanielKuppitz thanks for your response. Most of the matching is done OLTP, when importing the data, because it's needs to be resolved asap. I understand it will be a manual operation then (was hoping for some tinkerpop-api function). But because the import is highly concurrent and incoming data can be related to all vertices of the same entity I expect the vertices to-be-removed can get new properties or edges concurrent of the merge process. So I could lose data if I do not check/lock correctly. I have to think this one through a bit ...

Answer (score 5):

Alright, as mentioned in the comments above, you're going to do the matching in OLTP. That means you'll likely have a concrete entry point. Let's make up a simple sample graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()

// Stackoverflow data
g.addV("user").property("login", "user3508638").as("a").
  addV("user").property("login", "dkuppitz").property("age", 35).as("b").
  addV("question").property("title", "Tinkerpop/gremlin merge vertices (and edges)").as("c").
  addE("posted").from("a").to("c").
  addE("commented").from("b").to("c").property("time", 123).iterate()

// Github data
g.addV("user").property("login", "dkuppitz").property("name", "Daniel Kuppitz").as("a").
  addV("project").property("title", "TinkerPop").as("b").
  addE("contributed").from("a").to("b").iterate()
```

To match vertices based on login `dkuppitz` and merge them into a single user vertex:

```
g.V().has("login", "dkuppitz").
  fold().filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).unfold().
  sideEffect(properties().group("p").by(key).by(value())).
  sideEffect(outE().group("o").by(label).by(project("p","iv").by(valueMap()).by(inV()).fold())).
  sideEffect(inE().group("i").by(label).by(project("p","ov").by(valueMap()).by(outV()).fold())).
  sideEffect(drop()).
  cap("p","o","i").as("poi").
  addV("user").as("u").
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("p").unfold().as("kv").
    select("u").property(select("kv").select(keys), select("kv").select(values))).
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("o").unfold().as("x").
    select("u").sideEffect { u ->
      u.path("x").getValue().each { x ->
        def e = u.get().addEdge(u.path("x").getKey(), x.get("iv"))
        x.get("p").each { p ->
          e.property(p.getKey(), p.getValue())
        }
      }
    }).
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("i").unfold().as("x").
    select("u").sideEffect { u ->
      u.path("x").getValue().each { x ->
        def e = x.get("ov").addEdge(u.path("x").getKey(), u.get())
        x.get("p").each { p ->
          e.property(p.getKey(), p.getValue())
        }
      }
    }).iterate()
```

I know, the query is crazy complicated, especially with the deeply nested lambdas. But unfortunately there's no way around the lambdas, since we don't have an `addE(<traversal>)` overload (I created a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1793) though). Anyway, after executing the query above, the graph looks like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[login:[user3508638]]
==>[title:[Tinkerpop/gremlin merge vertices (and edges)]]
==>[title:[TinkerPop]]
==>[name:[Daniel Kuppitz],login:[dkuppitz],age:[35]]
gremlin> g.V().has("login", "dkuppitz").bothE()
==>e[19][15-commented->5]
==>e[20][15-contributed->12]
gremlin> g.V().has("login", "dkuppitz").bothE().valueMap(true)
==>[label:commented,time:123,id:19]
==>[label:contributed,id:20]
```

Both `dkuppitz` vertices were merged into one (`name` and `age` properties are present) and the 2 edges were recreated accordingly.

**UPDATE:**

With [TINKERPOP-1793](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1793) we can get rid of all lambdas:

```
g.V().has("login", "dkuppitz").
  fold().filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).unfold().
  sideEffect(properties().group("p").by(key).by(value())).
  sideEffect(outE().group("o").by(label).by(project("p","iv").by(valueMap()).by(inV()).fold())).
  sideEffect(inE().group("i").by(label).by(project("p","ov").by(valueMap()).by(outV()).fold())).
  sideEffect(drop()).
  cap("p","o","i").as("poi").
  addV("user").as("u").
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("p").unfold().as("kv").
    select("u").property(select("kv").select(keys), select("kv").select(values))).
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("o").unfold().as("x").select(values).
    unfold().addE(select("x").select(keys)).from(select("u")).to(select("iv"))).
  sideEffect(
    select("poi").select("i").unfold().as("x").select(values).
    unfold().addE(select("x").select(keys)).from(select("ov")).to(select("u"))).iterate()
```