# How to merge two vertices in JanusGraph and delete one of them. Also add the edges from deleted vertex to the modified vertex

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

There are two vertices A and B in JanusGraph. I am want to merge all the properties of vertex B in vertex A and delete vertex B. Also the edges if any associated with vertex B should be deleted but the same edges should be added to vertex A.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363737/tinkerpop-gremlin-merge-vertices-and-edges

Comment: In my case, I have some if-else condition(Each Vertex has a timestamp, properties of Vertex with latest timestamp will be given priority while merging ) while copying vertex data. Also need to change one property of all edges. My edges are having a property EID which the VID1-VID2 of connecting vertices.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample graph representing the initial state and then the expected outcome of the merge?